# ListBox with UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged in ItemsControl looses focus while typing

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, focus, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl which binds to an ObservableCollection with a simple class which contains two strings. For each Item of the collection two TextBoxes are shown. I set UpdateSourceTrigger of the Textbox binding to PropertyChanged because I need to detect changes of the values immediately.

The problem is when I start typing text into one of the Textboxes the focus of the Textbox is lost after pressing the first key. If I want to insert the next letter I have to click in the Textbox again. I don't know why the focus of the Textbox is lost after a change. Does anybody know how I can change this behavior?

When I remove the UpdateSourceTrigger part and use the default binding behavior everything works fine but this is no option for me becaue I need to detect a change immediately.

I also tried using ListBox or ListView instead of ItemsControl but the focus of the Textboxes is also lost after a change of the value.

Here is my declaration of the ItemsControl:

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I have created a window and added `ItemsControl` using your xaml, but was not able to reproduce the issue

Comment: Yes, the problem is not in the posted code. Maybe there's some event handling in code behind.

Comment: Ok you are right there was a error in event handling which caused the strange behavior. Thank you ASh and icebat, I should have checked this!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus or this is not acceptable with your program ?

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Is your problem still happening with this Trigger ?

Comment: The focus wouldn't be lost while typing but I couldn't register a change of the value until the user clicks somewhere else and this would be to late.